# Unable to change scenes in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

My phaser 3 game has a scene called **game** from which I call another scene **mainMenu** using **check()** method which is in load scene using:

```
//inside check() 
this.scene.start("mainMenu");
```

But this results in an error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined*

I believe it has something to with the **this** in the code but I am not sure. So how do I start a scene from a function.

**Load.js**

```
var config{
//game config goes here
scenes: [mainMenu,game]
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
function check(){
if(game over == true){
this.scene.start("mainMenu");}
}
```

**game.js**

```
class game extends Phaser.Scene {
constructor() {
super({ key: "game" });
}
create() {
 check();
}
}
```

Comment: Not a phaser issue, the error is telling you what the problem is "scene" is not defined. So your "this" reference may not be pointing to what you think it is (in js "this" can be misleading) or it is pointing to what you think it is and scene is just not defined...

Either way, impossible to tell without you showing us the whole class...so more detail would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the body of the check function "this" refers to the check function itself, which does not have the scene property on it, that's why you are seeing the error.

If you call check with the "call" method and pass the game's "this" it should fix your issue, but it's probably not the cleanest way to do this.

Also create I believe is only called on initialisation, so I don't imagine game over will ever be true at this point (you probably want to call that in update)

```
class game extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ key: "game" });
  }
  create() {
    check.call(this);
  }
}
```

Edit: The below is probably how I would approach the problem:

```
class MainScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ key: "MainScene" });
  }

  create() {}

  isGameOver() {
    // logic to determine if the game is over
  }

  update() {
    if (this.isGameOver()) {
      this.scene.start("MainMenu");
    }
  }
}

var config {
  //game config goes here
  scenes: [
    MainMenu,
    MainScene
  ]
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```