# Phaser3 Scene switching error. How can i do?

Tags: javascript, collision, phaser-framework, scene

I have this error when I touch a wall to change scene:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'start')

I tried several techniques but none worked, yet I have no other errors and my code is quite simple and I don't understand why it doesn't work...
Here is my code:

```js
class SceneMilieu extends Phaser.Scene {

  constructor() {
   super({key: 'sceneMilieu'});
 }


  //Chargement des images
  preload() {
    // this.load.image("Backgrond", "javascript/assets/Background.png");
    this.load.image("player", "javascript/assets/player.png");
    this.load.image("run1", "javascript/assets/run1.png");
    this.load.image("run2", "javascript/assets/run2.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun1", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun1.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun2", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun2.png");
    this.load.image("wall", "javascript/assets/wall.png");

  }

  create() {
    cursor = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys(); //touches des fleches

    var w = config.width;
    var h = config.height;

    //Les animations
    this.anims.create({
      key : "playerWalkUp",
      frames : [
        {key : "run1"},
        {key : "run2"}],
      frameRate : 7,
      repeat : 0
    })

    this.anims.create({
      key : "playerWalkLeft",
      frames : [
        {key : "playerLeftRun1"},
        {key : "playerLeftRun2"}],
      frameRate : 7,
      repeat : 0
    })

    // L'apparition + le controle et les collisions ce fais ci dessous

    // var backgroundImage = this.add.sprite(0, 0, "Background");
    // backgroundImage.setPosition(w/2, h/2);
    player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 300, "player"); //joueur
    player.setScale(1);
    player.body.setSize(30, 35);
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true); //collision avec la bordure

    doorLeft = this.physics.add.staticSprite(200, 400, "wall"); //Porte de tp

    var platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

    var wall = this.add.sprite(400, 500, "wall"); //mur
    

    this.physics.add.collider(platforms, player); //collision

    platforms.add(wall);
    
    function collision() {
      this.scene.start("sceneGauche");  
    }
    
    this.physics.add.collider(player, doorLeft, collision);
  }

  update() {

  // Tous les mouvement sont controler par ce code

    if (cursor.left.isDown){
      player.setVelocityX(-200); //vitesse de deplacements
      player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true); //animations du personnage
      player.setFlip(false, false); //oriantation de l'image
    } else if (cursor.right.isDown){
      player.setVelocityX(200);
      player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true);
      player.setFlip(true, false);
    } else if (cursor.up.isDown){
      player.setVelocityY(-200);
      player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
      player.setFlip(false, false);
    } else if (cursor.down.isDown){
      player.setVelocityY(200);
      player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
      player.setFlip(false, true);
    } else {
      player.setVelocity(0);
      player.setTexture("player");
    }

    if ((cursor.left.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.right.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.down.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.down.isDown)){
      player.setVelocity(0);
      player.setTexture("player");
    }

  //--------

}}

class SceneGauche extends Phaser.Scene {

  constructor() {
    super({key: "SceneGauche"});
    scene: {
      preload: this.preload;
      create: this.create;
      update: this.update;
    }
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.image("player", "javascript/assets/player.png");
    this.load.image("run1", "javascript/assets/run1.png");
    this.load.image("run2", "javascript/assets/run2.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun1", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun1.png");
    this.load.image("playerLeftRun2", "javascript/assets/playerLeftRun2.png");
    this.load.image("wall", "javascript/assets/wall.png");

  }

  create() {
    cursor = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    var w = config.width;
    var h = config.height;

    this.anims.create({
      key : "playerWalkUp",
      frames : [
        {key : "run1"},
        {key : "run2"}],
      frameRate : 7,
      repeat : 0
    })

    this.anims.create({
      key : "playerWalkLeft",
      frames : [
        {key : "playerLeftRun1"},
        {key : "playerLeftRun2"}],
      frameRate : 7,
      repeat : 0
    })

    player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 300, "player");
    player.setScale(1);
    player.body.setSize(30, 35);
    const border = player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

    var platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();

    var wall = this.add.sprite(400, 500, "wall");
    platforms.add(wall);

    this.physics.add.collider(platforms, player); 

    player.onCollide = new Phaser.signal(); 
    border.onCollide.add(changeMapGauche, this);

  }

  update() {

    if (cursor.left.isDown){
      player.setVelocityX(-200);
      player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true);
      player.setFlip(false, false);
    } else if (cursor.right.isDown){
      player.setVelocityX(200);
      player.anims.play("playerWalkLeft", true);
      player.setFlip(true, false);
    } else if (cursor.up.isDown){
      player.setVelocityY(-200);
      player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
      player.setFlip(false, false);
    } else if (cursor.down.isDown){
      player.setVelocityY(200);
      player.anims.play("playerWalkUp", true);
      player.setFlip(false, true);
    } else {
      player.setVelocity(0);
      player.setTexture("player");
    }

    if ((cursor.left.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.right.isDown) || (cursor.left.isDown && cursor.down.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.up.isDown) || (cursor.right.isDown && cursor.down.isDown)){
      player.setVelocity(0);
      player.setTexture("player");
    }
  }

}

var config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: window.innerWidth - 20,
  height: window.innerHeight - 100,
  backgroundColor: "#EDEED0",
  physics: {
    default : "arcade",
    arcade : {
      debug : true,
    }
  },
  scene: [SceneMilieu, SceneGauche]
};

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);

var cursor;
var player;
var doorLeft; 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr-FR">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Page web du projet de NSI. Ce site regrouppe quelque jeux en ligne programmer par nous même en javascript" />
    <meta name="author" content="Thorvald Helbling, Alexis STOCK, Lionel FUCHS" />
    <title>Thoralial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>

  </head>

  <header>

    <img id="LogoThoralial" src="info/image/LogoThoralial.png" alt="Logo du site" />

    <div>
      <h1>Bienvenue !</h1>
      <p>C'est votre tableau de bord.</p>
    </div>

  </header>

  <body>

    <script id="js" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/main.js"></script>
    <script></script>

  </body>

  <footer>
    
    <div id="personne">
      <p>
        Ce projet a étais réalisé par : <a href="***"> Thorvald HELBLING</a>, <a href="***"> Lionel FUCHS </a> et <a href="***"> Alexis STOCK </a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </footer>
</html>
```

I would like to understand where my error comes from and common fixed it.
I use Phaser3
The error comes from the site console. (Local)

Comment: Does this help? https://phaser.discourse.group/t/this-scene-is-undefined/2136/2 ? Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206071/unable-to-change-scenes-in-phaser-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line of code:

```
 this.physics.add.collider(player, doorLeft, collision);
```

You only need to pass the `scene` as context to the `collider` function. Here is a link to the documentation, especially for the `collider` function and parameters. https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.52.0/focus/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Factory-collider

With other words, you just have to pass the `scene` context (as parameter 5) and a *should process function* (parameter 4, in this case `undefined`, since there is no function)

Just replace the current line, with this line *(or add the two parameters)*, and it should work

```
  this.physics.add.collider(player, doorLeft, collision, undefined, this);
```

Or you can use the javascript function `bind`:

```
  this.physics.add.collider(player, doorLeft, collision.bind(this));
```

Might not be as obvious, but it is shorter and works fine ([Link to `bind` documentaion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)). This would be my prefered mehtod, **if** I don't use the parameter 4, since the code likes much cleaner and shorter this way.

**Update:** Alternativly if you want to use **Closures** you could change only the function definition, to a [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), then you would not have to pass any extra parameter, do the `collider` function:

```
   let collision = () => {
       this.scene.start("sceneGauche");  
   }
```

> *I'm in usually no fan of defining functions inside of function/methods (especially with the `function` keyword), but with the **arrow function expression**, it's looks even abit cleaner.*

Comment: Great, thats work, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. :) If you could accept the answer, that would be great.